# Google App Engine and Django support

Tags: django, google-app-engine, pycharm

I'm trying to deploy my `Django` app to `Google App Engine` (GAE) as per [this document](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django). I created and configured a `Google Cloud SQL` instance, as described in that document. I use `PyCharm` as development environment and created a GAE project with Django support.

I configured a local server to point to the GAE server. When I try to launch the GAE local server in PyCharm, it's raising exceptions on an improperly configured database in `SETTINGS.PY`:

```
google.appengine.ext.django.backends.rdbms' isn't an available database backend
```

I can see from the stack trace that the local server is using the Django version in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` while I presume it should use the one in `/usr/local/google_appengine/lib`.

What would be the best way to solve this given that I have other Django projects as well that should use the Django version in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`? If I modify my `PYTHONPATH` to include the GAE version of Django, would not all my projects be referencing that version of Django?

**EDIT:** To be more precise, the GAE local server starts just fine but throws the mentioned stack trace when I do a `syncdb` task to update my database.

**EDIT 2:** In PyCharm Settings under Python Interpreter, I found the possibility to modify paths and added the Django 1.4 version as distributed with GAE SDK. When I start the GAE development server, I can actually see it uses the Django version from the GAE SDK but it still crashes on the database definitions:

```
Error was: No module named google.appengine.ext.django.backends.rdbms.base
```

**EDIT 3:** I ran into problems when trying to deploy an existing Django app using the tutorial. See [this separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187640/google-app-engine-aborts-on-missing-environment-variable-django-settings-module).

Comment: how did you install django-appengine? best way is to use the modified django-nonrel package listed in the tutorials

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo: Django is now prepackaged with GAE SDK. I followed the linked document from Google Developers which was updated on December 14th 2012, so should reflect recent status. The nonrel version of Django was targeted at BigData; the version described in the document should support Google Cloud SQL which is relational.

Comment: Do you have a local MySQL running? In other words, when you run the SDK, do you get this message "WARNING  2013-01-04 01:58:04,612 rdbms_mysqldb.py:74] The rdbms API is not available because the MySQLdb library could not be loaded."?

Comment: @Sologoub: I have a local MySQL running when running the SDK. The message you mention does not appear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like PyCharms call of `syncdb` is using the wrong Django installation.
`google.appengine.ext.django.backends.rdbms` is not part of the official Django distribution, but it is part of GAEs django.
My GAE django is in `/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/`

If you're on linux/OS X you could add this to your `.bashrc`/`.bash_profile` and make syncdb use this:

```
export GAE="/usr/local/google_appengine"
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:$GAE:$GAE/lib/django_1_4"
export PATH=${PATH}:$GAE/lib/django_1_4/django/bin/
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

I wrote a [tutorial about using Django with GAE and Google Cloud SQL](http://howto.pui.ch/post/39245389801/tutorial-django-1-4-on-appengine-using-google-cloud). There might be some relevant infos there as well.

Comment: wow, thanks a lot, glad you like it. I'd be happy if you could spread the word about it ;-)

Comment: @PhilippKeller your tutorial helped a lot thank you :)

Comment: @PhilippKeller: same here!