# What are the best approaches to convert Django app to Google App Engine?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I may be late to the party, but I've been playing around with Google App Engine.
My plan was to convert an existing open-source Django app to run on GAE.

I went through the O'reilly book, Programming Google App Engine to get the gist of GAE.
I'm ready to start diving in, but I'm curious as to the best way to approach it.

I Django-nonrel currently the best option to use?

My Google-fu isn't really turning up many examples of people converting a Django app to run on GAE. The few that I have found seem to date to 2010 or earlier. Is this because people are not finding it worthwhile to use GAE with Django?

What has been your experience porting Django apps to GAE?

Comment: I use django nonrel, and find it works well.  You will need to check your current database calls, to check if you do any `JOINS`, because those are verboten.  You may find the migration easier if you use the sql database, if your current database is relational.  My biggest challenge was to completely re-do my db schema to use the non-relational datastore (Did it before CloudSQL was available). I have seen rumors that nonrel may get merged into django soon, which would certainly be a plus.

Comment: Also, you will not use the Django version that GAE provides.  You will use the nonrel version, and some helper packages: djangoappengine, djangotoolbox, dbindexer, etc.  Come on in, the water's warm!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google App Engine now supports SQL databases so you can have a regular django app on GAE. [Here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django) is the official documentation, and [here](http://howto.pui.ch/post/39245389801/tutorial-django-on-appengine-using-google-cloud-sql) is a nice tutorial from another [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137404/google-app-engine-and-django-support).

I have personally run django sql (and nonrel) apps on gae and they have been fine.